# How to get $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n+1)(n+1)}$?

Tags: analysis

How to get $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n+1)(n+1)}$ ?

The following picture is what I try. I can't deal $x=\pm 1$.

[image]

[image]

Comment: $xF(x)=\color{red}{x-\ln(1+x)}$, and why $\ln(1\color{red}{-}x)$ later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $\dfrac{1}{(2n+1)(n+1)}=\dfrac{2}{2n+1}-\dfrac{1}{n+1}$, and you get simpler power series.

Answer (score 1):

$(-1)^nx^{2n}=(ix)^{2n}$

Write $$\dfrac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(n+1)(2n+1)}$$

$$=a\dfrac{(ix)^{2n+2}}{2n+2}+b\dfrac{(ix)^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$

Multiply both sides by $(2n+2)(2n+1)$

Now set $2n+1=0$ and $2n+2=0$ one by one 
 to find $a,b$

Now use $\ln(1+x),\ln(1-x)$ formula

Answer (score 0):

Let's add and subtract a term to start the series at $0$

$$-1+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{(2n+1)(n+1)}$$

Then as metamorphy suggests, use partial fractions to get

$$-1 + \frac{2}{x}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{2n+1} - \frac{1}{x^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n \left(x^2\right)^{n+1}}{n+1}$$

Then recognize the series as the ones for $\arctan(z)$ and $\log(1+z)$, respectively

$$-1 +\frac{2\arctan(x)}{x} - \frac{\log\left(1+x^2\right)}{x^2}$$

The limit is finite as $x\to 0$ so it's only a removable discontinuity (hole) with a value of $0$. This makes the formula valid for $|x|\leq 1$, with

$$x=\pm 1 \implies \frac{\pi}{2} - \log(2) - 1$$